# kartik\datecontrol\DateControl not found

Tags: php, datepicker, yii2, yii2-basic-app, kartik-v

I've used [mootensai/yii2-enhanced-gii](https://github.com/mootensai/yii2-enhanced-gii) and they said I should add this code at `config\main.php`:

```
'modules' => [

  'gridview' => [
      'class' => '\kartik\grid\Module',
      // see settings on http://demos.krajee.com/grid#module
  ],
  'datecontrol' => [
      'class' => '\kartik\datecontrol\Module',
      // see settings on http://demos.krajee.com/datecontrol#module
  ],
  // If you use tree table
  'treemanager' =>  [
      'class' => '\kartik\tree\Module',
      // see settings on http://demos.krajee.com/tree-manager#module
  ]

],
```

I am using Yii2 Basic so I add it to `config/web.php` like below

```
  'components' => [
  // some code here !
],

'modules' => [

          'gridview' => [
              'class' => '\kartik\grid\Module',
          ],
          'datecontrol' => [
              'class' => '\kartik\datecontrol\Module',
          ],

          'treemanager' =>  [
              'class' => '\kartik\tree\Module',
          ]

        ],
```

So when I run the generated code from Gii it gives me the code for date filed like this:

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'regester_end_date')->widget(\kartik\datecontrol\DateControl::classname(), [
    'type' => \kartik\datecontrol\DateControl::FORMAT_DATE,
    'saveFormat' => 'php:Y-m-d',
    'ajaxConversion' => true,
    'options' => [
        'pluginOptions' => [
            'placeholder' => Yii::t('app', 'Choose Regester End Date'),
            'autoclose' => true
        ]
    ],
]); ?>
```

When I run my form, it gives me a problem that says `Class 'kartik\datecontrol\DateControl' not found`. I updated the composer and I install the the kartik widgets and there is nothing happens

Comment: You have installed DateControl?

Comment: I install this `$ php composer.phar require kartik-v/yii2-widgets "*"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`kartik-v/yii2-datecontrol` is not part of `kartik-v/yii2-widgets` nor `mootensai/yii2-enhanced-gii`, you need to install it separately:

```
composer require kartik-v/yii2-datecontrol
```